# Generation of facial expressions

Tags: expression, neural-network, cg, emotion

How are facial expressions usually created in computer games/CG graphics? Are they made "by hand", or do people use algorithms to generate a facial expression out of a given set of parameters (e.g. something like different emotion values)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe they capture facial expressions of real actors and transform them to 3d models of the game characters, so i guess it falls under the 'by hand' category.
i am not familiar with an algorithmic way of generating facial expression.

see [Facial motion capture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facial_motion_capture) on wikipedia